# How to add a text logo in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out how to change the logo.

The code that the current logo sits in looks like this.

```
var brand = (
 <div className={classes.logo}>
  <p className={classes.logoLink}>
   Material Dashboard
  </p>
 </div>
)
```

Here's what I'm not understanding though, the logo itself says something different than "Material Dashboard" so I'm not sure where that's coming from.

All I want to do is change the logo. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`classes.logo` is probably a css class (inspect with chrome browser to see the value of the class attribute, for example xxx). Go to the css file and find the line with `.xxx { ...` and you should be able to change the logo